# How to use idiom "Not a moment too soon"

Tags: idioms

The meaning of idiom **not a moment too soon**  is **almost too late**
It is used as-

> The ambulance arrived not a moment too soon.

If I form the sentence in the following-

> The ambulance did not arrive a moment too soon.

Would this be grammatical or idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When expressing the idea of something happening only just in time, it is perfectly acceptable to say "The ambulance didn't (or did not) arrive too soon, or a moment too soon". One is not restricted to the form "[something happened] not a moment too soon". One can say that something didn't happen a moment too soon.

> - But for hissing audiences, **it didn't happen a moment too soon**. But
>     before this picture, Fox had given Donlevy the opportunity to play
>     comedy on screen. (*Gunmen and Gangsters: Profiles of Nine Actors Who
>     Portrayed Memorable Screen Tough Guys* By Michael Schlossheimer)
> - It **didn't happen a moment too soon**. President Yeltsin was not
>     exaggerating when he likened the current situation in his country...
>     (*LA Times*)
> - And the change **didn't happen a moment too soon**. (*Baltimore Sun*)
> - ... sin has won in the Middle Atlantic states, and the response of the
>     populace suggests that **it didn't happen a moment too soon**. (*Aiken
>     Standard*)
> - Yoenis Cespedes' bat and Steven Matz's left arm **didn't arrive a moment
>     too soon**. (*New York Post*)
> - His suitability as a flirtatious Irish stable hand is hard to see –
>     all told, The Maltese Falcon (1940) **didn't arrive a moment too soon**.
>     (UK *Daily Telegraph* - very strict on style)
> - It **didn't arrive a moment too soon** for worried residents of Seward
>     (*Chicago Tribune*)

Comment: I did find this in the UK Metro (a free newspaper): "And it doesn't look like it wasn't a moment too soon for the 25-year-old Little Mix singer and her Liverpool footballer boyfriend." Clearly the writer got in a muddle about the litotes aspect and decided to sprinkle plenty of negation into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

It's less common--and less preferable in my opinion--to place *not* in front of *arrive,* in the case of your example, because a reader will likely become distracted by the idea that the ambulance did not arrive at all.

It is more clearly and carefully used like this:

> The ambulance arrived not a moment too soon.

It is even more common to include *and* in the expression. Something like:

> Then the ambulance arrived. And not a moment too soon, for she was about to die.